# treating array keys as different variable in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have one dimensional array as below

```
$arr=array("a"=>'1',"b"=>2,'c'=>'3');
```

i need to use keys of array i.e a,b,c as variable .. so that

`echo $a` should display `1` , `$b` should display `2` and so on

possible in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`extract()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3
);
extract($arr);

echo $a; // = 1
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this.. miles better than my answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

`extract($arr)`

Is the correct answer to this question.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Its generally not considered a good idea though. Whats wrong with `$arr['a']`?

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in function for this called extract()

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 1):

I just do it like this for basic arrays

```
$arr=array("a"=>'1',"b"=>2,'c'=>'3');
foreach($arr as $k=$v){ $$k=$v; }

echo $a; //prints 1
echo $c; //prints 3
```

EDIT: Check FDL's answer

Comment: @downvoter - please share why you downvoted since the above does work and I've used it flawlessly as long as I can remember. I also sent the questioner to what I feel is a better answer than mine (FDL)